# MFP 8 - Connection Error

Tags: mobilefirst-server

I'm running the MFP server in my local. I logged in and see the dashboard page.
But am getting connection error in dashboard. Below is the error message

Connection error. Contact the server administrator(HTPP code: 1)

Comment: Can you refresh and see if dashboaed loads properly?

Comment: Can you upload the server log?